# area of triangle

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC$ points $D,E,F$ are on the sides $AB,BC,CA$, respectively, with $AD=DB$, $CE=3BE$ and $AF=2CF$. If the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $480 cm^2$, how do we find the area of $\triangle DEF$?

Comment: I suggest the use of vectors

Comment: Vector is not in my curriculum yet.I need something simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate the area of $ADF, BDE, ECF$. Subtract their sum from $ABC$ to get $DEF$.

---

**Further Hint:** $\frac{\mbox{Area } ADF } { \mbox {Area } ABC } = \frac{ AD } { AB} \times \frac { AF} { AC} $.

Comment: That is what I thought.Didn't help.

Comment: @rahul See the further hint.

Comment: This is a rather old question,but can you please tell me how you obtain those ratios?

Comment: @rah4927 They have a common angle of $ABC$, and it follows by the ratio of the lengths. Alternatively, if you know the sine rule area formula, Area $ABC = AB \times AC \times \sin \angle ABC$, then the result follows directly.

Comment: How is ABC a common angle?Is it equal to DAC?Also,how does it follow from the ratio of the lengths?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Drop the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$ and $D$ to $AC$, and use that to find the area of $\triangle DAF$.

Use same idea for others.

Answer (score 1):

Denote 
$$
\vec a = \vec{AB}, \qquad \vec b = \vec{AC}
$$
Then
$$
\vec c = -\vec a + \vec b
$$
and
$$
\vec{DE} = \frac12 \vec a + \frac14 (-\vec a + \vec b) = \frac14 \vec a + \frac14 \vec b
$$
$$
\vec{DF} = -\frac12 a + \frac23 \vec b
$$
Area of the $\triangle DEF$ can be calculated as 
$$
\frac12 |\vec{DE} \times \vec{DF}| = \frac12 |(\frac14 \vec a + \frac14 \vec b) \times (-\frac12 a + \frac23 \vec b)| = \frac{7}{48} |\vec a \times \vec b|
$$
since $\vec a \times \vec a = \vec b \times \vec b = 0$ and $\vec a \times \vec b = \vec b \times \vec a$.

Area of $\triangle ABC$ is also
$$
\frac12 |\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| = 480
$$
implying
$$
|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| = 960
$$
Area of $\triangle DEF$ is therefore
$$
\frac{7}{48} \cdot 960 = 140
$$